# Getting a Box2D body created in C++ to collide with Box2D bodies in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, box2d, qtquick2

I am using the qml-box2d library. I would like to create a Box2D body with fixtures in C++ and use it in QML. Unfortunately, any time I create a `b2Body` object and create fixtures for the object my app crashes. If I use the `Box2DBody` object, that comes with the qml-box2d library, it doesn't show in QML.

I need the Box2D body with fixtures in C++ to collide with all Box2D bodies in QML. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Can you post your code here? Btw, you have not create `b2Body` directly. Create `Box2DBody` object in your code and expose it to `QML`. Any way, it's not visual item and should be attached to any `QML` visual item throught `target` property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pay attention - `Box2DBody` is not visual item since it derived from `QObject`. It only adds physical properties to its `target`. Anyway, I think the easiest way to create physical bodies is to do that in `QML`. But if you still want to do that in C++ you can use the code below. Suppose, we have a scene in `main.qml` with a QML `rect` item:

```js
Window {
    width: 800
    height: 600
    visible: true

    World {}

    Rectangle {
        objectName: "rect"
        width: 100
        height: 100
        x: 350
        y: 50
        color: "green"
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: floor
        height: 50
        anchors {
            left: parent.left
            right:  parent.right
            bottom: parent.bottom
        }
        color: "brown"
        Body {
            target: floor
            fixtures: Box {
                width: floor.width
                height: floor.height
                density: 0.5
                friction: 0.5
                restitution: 0.5
            }
        }
    }

    DebugDraw {
        visible: true
        opacity: 0.7
    }
}
```

And now we want to "revive" it:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    Box2DPlugin plugin;
    plugin.registerTypes("Box2D");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    QObject *root = engine.rootObjects()[0];
    QQuickItem *rect = root->findChild<QQuickItem *>("rect");

    Box2DBody * body = new Box2DBody(root);
    body->setBodyType(Box2DBody::Dynamic);
    body->setTarget(rect);
    Box2DBox * fixture = new Box2DBox(rect);
    fixture->setWidth(rect->width());
    fixture->setHeight(rect->height());
    fixture->setDensity(0.8);
    fixture->setFriction(0.5);
    fixture->setRestitution(0.5);
    body->addFixture(fixture);
    body->componentComplete();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: It worked flawlessly! Thanks again! I am doing it from C++ because I'm trying to extend a library that uses qml-box2d.